# Get Items in Backbone Collection

Tags: collections, backbone.js

First - I'm new to Backbone, so bear with the possibly stupid nature of this question. I have a model:

```
var AppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        mynumber: null
    }

});
```

I can successfully add items dynamically to the collection (`console.log` shows that they're going in fine), but I'm just not sure how to pull them out, here's what I'm trying:

```
printCollection: function(){
    this.collection.each(function(item){
        console.log(item.mynumber);
    });
}
```

Which shows the number of items and `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the attribute accessor, not the value.

```
item.get('mynumber');
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple!